# How to get first or last vertex of a loose edge in Python?

Tags: python, selection-tools

I wish to select the first vertex of each loose part in my object. How can I do that with code?

[image: loose edges in space]

Comment: That depends on how you want to define 'first' versus 'last'.  It's easy enough to find the end points on loose edges: They're the vertices that only have 1 edge attached. But without knowing your definition of 'first' it's impossible to pick between them.

Comment: @MartyFouts thank you Marty, that is definitely something I can work with. As for telling which end is which, an example that comes to mind would be Houdini where the points are numbered and you can for example assume that lower point number will be the first/bottom vertex. Not long ago blender introduced a Spreadsheet tab -- do vertices in blender have their own numbers that we can access by any chance?

Comment: Vertices have their own numbers, but they're unique within the entire mesh, rather than unique to an edge loop. One of the edges might have 3, 4, 5, and 6 and the next one 17, 19 and 21, depending on how they were created.

Comment: @MartyFouts Same as in Houdini. My idea is that you can just pick the lower number of the two. Perfect!